# How to register Performance Counters Manifest using VS2008 Installer

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, installation, performancecounter

I have a VC++ (unmanaged) project to which I added [performance counters using manifest method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Everything is working great and I even have build steps that do manifest compilation and automatic registration using lodctr.exe tool with /m:manifest switch.

The problem that I'm running into is that I now need to make installer (VS2008 Installer project) do registration on install (unregistration on uninstall).

I tried to set it up by having a custom action that referenced lodctr.exe tool with `CustomActionData` set to `/m:[TARGETDIR]PerfMon.manifest` and similar setup using unlodctr.exe for custom uninstall action.

When installer runs, I do see a brief flash of cmd window (which is ok), but counters are not getting registered.  I ran SysInternals' ProcMon tool, and I don't see lodctr.exe process even created.

I tested that running lodctr.exe manually on target machine registers the counters.

I googled for an example or explanation how to do it with Visual Studio installer project, but came up empty.  It has some .NET oriented examples, but nothing for unmanaged, hard and cold VC++...

How can I register performance counters manifest using installer project?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio installer project has very limited functionality. Starting from Visual Studio 2012 Visual Studio installer project is not supported, [you should consider to use Windows Installer XML (WIX) instead](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3570f0b3-53c1-4d2e-94fe-16ed7af70bbf/where-is-visual-studio-2012-setup-project-template).

Include your manifest into WIX project and use WIX's [PerfCounterManifest](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/perfcountermanifest.html) with it.